# Set height to percent of width?

Tags: css

This is what I want to do:

```
#sheet {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: calc(width * 1.3181818181818181818181818181818);
}
```

`#sheet` looks like this:

```
<div id="sheet">
    <img src="sheet1.svg"/>
</div>
```

The width of `#sheet` varies depending on the size of your browser. The height (presently) depends on the height of `sheet1.svg`. But I know the width to height ratio of `sheet1.svg`, and I would like to encode that in the CSS so that the `#sheet` div can be sized correctly before the SVG loads in. I need the div to be sized correctly, because I have some other code that depends on that...

CSS3 adds the [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) method, but I don't think you can do calculations based on other properties....so how can I dot his?

Comment: with css .... you can't

Comment: @Danko: That's a bummer.

Comment: I hope `calc()` can evolve fast to make things like this it will be much easier

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It can be done CSS only:

```
#sheet {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50%; /* Your percentage */
}
#sheet > img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/D66wu/)

It works because if you use a percentage in `padding-top`, it is relative to width. Then, you can use padding instead of height, using `position: absolute` to children in order to have a 0px tall parent.

Comment: 1+ Great way to think outside of the box :) I definitely wouldn't have thought of this!

Comment: If we alert the height immediately (http://jsfiddle.net/D66wu/1/) it says 0. Are you sure the sheet has a height prior to the image loading?

Comment: @Mark See http://jsfiddle.net/D66wu/2/. Your fiddle alerts `0` because I replaced height with padding, which `.height()` doesn't include (http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/)

Comment: Impressively genius!

Comment: +1 This is the best CSS work around for solving this issue I have seen. Hopefully aspect-ratio will eventually roll out to the other browsers (not just chrome) though and we can stop doing things like this.

Answer (score 3):

I've done it with a lot of jQuery hackery:

```
var $svg = $(document.getElementById('svg'));
var $sheet = $(document.getElementById('sheet'));

$svg.on('load', function() {
    $(window).off('.setSheetHeight');
    $sheet.css('height', '');
});

var setSheetHeight = function() {
    $sheet.height($sheet.width() * 1.3181818181818181818181818181818);
};

setSheetHeight();
$(window).on('resize.setSheetHeight orientationchange.setSheetHeight', _.throttle(setSheetHeight,100));
```

It immediately sets the sheet height to 1.32x its width. Once the SVG loads, the browser can compute the height of the sheet on its own, so I clear the height style and remove the event listener to save some CPU. I also throttle the event (using underscore) so it doesn't fire too often.

If you're curious, I then use the sheet height to resize some text on the page:

```
function setFontSize() {
    $('input:text').css('font-size',$sheet.height()/80);
}

setFontSize();
$(window).on('resize.setFontSize orientationchange.setFontSize', _.throttle(setFontSize, 100));
```

Since we can't set `font-size` relative to its container's height, apparently.

Comment: 1+ Glad you figured something out. I was going to suggest something similar to this, as it currently can't be achieved with pure CSS.. eventually there will be **[variables in CSS](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/)**.. so it might be possible one day.. See this example given with variables and `calc()` http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/#cycles

Comment: @JoshC It CAN be done CSS only. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20157916/1529630)